# Edit Options Menu after receiving data from an asyncronous task

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-optionsmenu

I am implementing the In-App Billing service in my app. I set up in `onCreate()` the call to the `IabHelper.queryInventoryAsync()` to retrieve previous purchases. If the item is purchased, I set a global boolean variable to true. Meanwhile, in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, I check that variable whether to remove a MenuItem or not. My problem is that `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, as expected, is sometimes called before the async task is done setting my boolean variable. I need a solution to tell `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to wait for that task to set the boolean value, so that it can create the menu accordingly. Here's the code in detail:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

//other  stuff...

   helper.queryInventoryAsync(new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
                public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                                     Inventory inventory) {

                    if (result.isFailure()) {
                        // handle error here   
                        return;                        
                    }

                    if (inventory.hasPurchase(REMOVE_ADS_SKU)) {  
                        //item purchased. set control variable
                        isNoAds = true;
                    } 

                }
            });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    //if the control variable is true, remove the option to buy ad-free version
    if (isNoAds) menu.removeItem(R.id.action_remove_ads);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that the most robust way to do this is by invalidating the whole menu. So, when you get your async result (in `onQueryInventoryFinished`) just call:

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

or, if you are using a `FragmentActivity` (`SherlockFragmentActivity` or `ActionBarActivity`)

```
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```

In this way the menu will be recreated and you can safely add or remove items as you need.

Comment: this appears to cleanly solve the problem, as it seems that invalidateOptionsMenu() doesn't need any reference to the menu itself and there's no evident risk to incur in an exception in case the call is made when the menu isn't created yet, which is my concern since the method is placed in the onCreate(). I did think of this solution but I'm using api 10 and I missed the fact that there's a compatibility version of this method :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `onPrepareOptionMenu` might do the trick. The docs (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) states that it's used to prepare what should be displayed. You keep the xml inflate in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` and then do the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_remove_ads).setVisible(!isNoAds);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

You still initialize the `isNoAds` variable to true in the `onCreate` method to be sure it's not displayed immediatly.

Comment: I believe this is the most straightforward solution, but the MenuItem is still visible if the menu is opened right after the ui is shown, when the task hasn't set the variable yet. With a common use (no one usually opens the menu right after they open an app), this might be ok, but the solution above seems to be the most robust. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You might simply initialize the isNoAds to true in the onCreate method, this way it will not be visibile and you have no further processing to do.